# How can I count the number of nodes in a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtree

I am using [JIDE's CheckBoxTree](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/CheckBoxTree.html) to display a nested tree of checkboxes, as in this example:

[image: example image]

I would like to know how many nodes the tree model contains.

If I call the method [tree.getModel().getChildCount(rootNode)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html#getChildCount%28java.lang.Object%29), I only get the number of direct children (e.g. 12 in this case), and NOT the number of any children nested further (20+).

Comment: traverse the model and count :-) If the nodes are of type DefaultMutableTreeNode, there's api doing it. If you are (by any chance :) using SwingX, it has utility methods to travers an arbitrary model. Else, look at the code and implement yourself.

Comment: you have to recursively check and count all nodes. that way you can also ignore folder nodes if you want that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursively:

```
public int getNumberOfNodes(TreeModel model)  
{  
    return getNumberOfNodes(model, model.getRoot());  
}  

private int getNumberOfNodes(TreeModel model, Object node)  
{  
    int count = 1;
    int nChildren = model.getChildcount(node);  
    for (int i = 0; i < nChildren; i++)  
    {  
        count += getNumberOfNodes(model, model.getChild(node, i));  
    }  
    return count;  
}
```

Comment: getChildcount should be getChildCount (Uppercase 'c' for 'Count')

Answer (score 2):

Traverse the tree yourself using the `getChild()` method.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: I was finding it particularly difficult to get an accurate count, as nodes with children were being counted twice.